# XML to CSV data export

Tags: powershell

I have 100 zip files with 10-20 xml for each zip file. I need to export specific tag element to csv.
For example i have 20 zip file with 10 xml each(20*10=200) 200 lines are should present in one csv.

Example XML Code :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <bookstore>
      <book category="children">
        <title>Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2019</year>
        <price>20.99</price>
      </book>
    </bookstore>
```

I need to export title and price in to csv.

Comment: in your question you need to include what you've tried so far to solve the problem

Comment: what part are you having problems with? getting the files out of the ZIP archives? getting the content of the files? converting to XML objects? getting the two properties you want? exporting to CSV? ///// you have not asked a question ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

try Something like this:

```
[Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')  

#take all zip files
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\test1" -file -Filter "*.zip" | %{

        #take only xml file
        [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($_.FullName).Entries | where Fullname -like "*.xml" | %{

        #extract xml only
        $PathXMLFileextracted="C:\temp\" + $_.name
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($_, $PathXMLFileextracted, $true)

        #take content of xml
        [XML] $xml=get-content $PathXMLFileextracted

        #remove new xml created (for clean)
        Remove-Item $PathXMLFileextracted

        #take necessary data
        $xml.bookstore.book | select title, price
        }


} | export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -NoTypeInformation # export result to csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a start.  The key is to cast to [xml].  There's no "import-xml" cmdlet. 
 You'll want to select what you want from the powershell $xml object before exporting to csv.  $xml.save('file.xml') to export it back to xml.

```
PS /Users/js> [xml]$xml = get-content file.xml
PS /Users/js> $xml

xml                            bookstore
---                            ---------
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" bookstore

PS /Users/js> $xml | export-csv file.csv
PS /Users/js> get-content file.csv
"xml","bookstore"
"version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""","System.Xml.XmlElement"
```

Answer (score 0):

So.... this....

```
[xml]$XmlDoc = @'
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<bookstore>
    <book category="children">
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2019</year>
    <price>20.99</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
'@


$XmlDoc.bookstore.book | 
Select-Object -Property title, price

# Results

title        price
-----        -----
Harry Potter 20.99



$XmlDoc.bookstore.book | 
Select-Object -Property title, price | 
Export-Csv -Path 'E:\Temp\BookList.csv'

Import-Csv -Path 'E:\Temp\BookList.csv'

# Results

title        price
-----        -----
Harry Potter 20.99
```